# How to write xpath for dynamic elements in python/selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a tab called source control,That tab has an id  which is dynamically generated.on looking online ,tried below methods but still no use

Tried the below xpath:

```
//li[@class="menu-item"]/a/strong[text(),Source Control]')
//li[@class="menu-item"]//a//text()[preceding-sibling::strong][normalize-space()!='']
//li//a[starts-with(id,"aui-uid-")]/strong[text(),Source Control]
```

Code that i am using

```
Sourcecontrol=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a/strong[text(),Source Control]')
if not Sourcecontrol:
    print("No element found")  
else:
    Sourcecontrol.click();
```

HTML

```
<li class="menu-item" role="presentation">
                    <a href="link" id="aui-uid-4" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><strong>Source Control</strong></a>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath.It will search the substring inside anchor element.Try use following options

```
try:
 Sourcecontrol=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a[contains(.,"Source Control")]')
 Sourcecontrol.click();
except:
 print("No element found")
```

Or

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a[contains(.,"Source Control")]'))>0:
   Sourcecontrol = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@class="menu-item"]/a[contains(.,"Source Control")]')
   Sourcecontrol.click();
else:
    print("No element found")
```